# Python Printing Diagonal Pattern

Tags: python

I want to print a diagonal pattern like this -

[image]

However, I'm able to get only this output -

[image]

Here is my code -

```
for i in range (0,5):
    for j in range(0,i):
        print(" ", end = "")
    print(i)
    print(" ")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prepare a string of spaces and print a substring of it on each line starting at the positon if the current index:

```
n = 4
spaces = " "*n
for i in range(n+1):
    print(spaces[i:],i)

     0
    1
   2
  3
 4
```

Comment: Probably better to use `sep=''` for extra space added in every line.

Answer (score 2):

Store the number of spaces you need in every iteration with `space = n - i`(for number `0` you need 4 spaces). Insert the spaces before the actual number here `i`. The reason why you need  `n + 1` instead of `n` is because the range is up to but not include the second agrument.

```
n = 4

for i in range(n + 1):
    space = n - i
    print(f"{' ' * space}{i}")
```

output :

```
    0
   1
  2
 3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to run 2 loops, all you need is to count the number of spaces in every line and try to find the pattern of spaces and the numbers of stars:

```
n = 5
for i in range(0, n):
    print((n-i)*" "+str(i))
```

```
     0
    1
   2
  3
 4
```